# Basic question regarding change of variable in contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am looking at the following integral
$$
\int |x^s| ds,
$$
where the integral goes from $\sigma -iT$ to $\sigma + iT$ (along $Re(s) = \sigma$). I am expecting that the integral is real because the function is real. Let $s = \sigma + it.$ However, if I do a change of variable so that I take the integral with respect to $t$, I get the following:

Since $s = \sigma + i t$, I get $ds = i dt$.
So the integral above becomes
$$
\int_{-T}^T x^{\sigma} \ i \ dt,
$$
and this gives me a purely imaginary number. But I thought the integral was supposed to be real... Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here (or where there is an error in my logic)? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Is $x$ real valued?  If so, is $x>0$?

Comment: Yes, x> 0 here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct, and your expectation that the result would be real is wrong. That the integral over a real-valued function is real is only true for integration in $\mathbb R$, where the measure is also real-valued. In this line integral, while the integrand is real, you can informally regard $\mathrm ds$ as an infinitesimal increment along the path, and for this particular path this increment is purely imaginary. Looking at [the definition of the complex line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Complex_line_integral), you can see that this informal intuition corresponds to purely imaginary finite increments along the path in the Riemann sum.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Greatly appreciated!!